# When creating a order via Woocommerce Rest API order note showing two notes for order status and also Not sending a correct email

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Facing an issue when creating a order via WooCommerce rest API. There are two issues:

1. Order Note
   When creating order via Desktop:-
   New Order of "BANK Transfer" as a payment creating two order note
2. Order status changed from pending payment to on hold
3. For order stock reduced

When creating order via Mobile:-
New order with "Bank Transfer" as a payment method creating three order note:-
1. Order status changed from pending payment to processing
2. Order stock reduced
3. Order status changed from pending payment to on hold

2. Customer Receiving a email with status processing, while the order status is on-hold

I tried to pass order status=on-hold from API when creating a order and updating a order payment details. But issue is still persist.

Order create api

POST wc-api/v3/orders/

Body
 `{
  "order": {
    "customer_id": 6925,
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "Android",
      "last_name": "Testing",
      "address_1": "Address of Developer",
      "address_2": "Cengkareng",
      "city": "Jakarta Barat",
      "state": "6",
      "postcode": "12345",
      "country": "ID",
      "email": "ankurgecr@gmail.com",
      "phone": "1234567890"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "Android",
      "last_name": "Testing",
      "address_1": "Address of Developer",
      "address_2": "Cengkareng",
      "city": "Jakarta Barat",
      "state": "6",
      "postcode": "12345",
      "country": "ID"
    },
    "line_items": [
      {
        "product_id": 32776,
        "quantity": 1,
        "subtotal": 10000,
        "total": 10000,
        "variations": {
          "Color": "Blue"
        }
      }
    ],
    "fee_lines": [
      {
        "title": "Rp",
        "total": 846
      }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "method_id": "OKE",
        "method_title": "JNE OKE",
        "total": 29500
      }
    ],
    "is_vat_exempt": false
  }
}`

Order update API

POST  wc-api/orders/[orderID]

BODY 
`{
  "order": {
    "status": "on-hold",
    "payment_details": {
      "method_id": "bacs",
      "method_title": "Bank Transfer BCA / MANDIRI",
      "paid": true
    },
    "set_paid": true
  }
}`

Custoemr should receive a email of order status= on-hold.

I'm attaching a image for actual result.

Note: Is is working fine if we are placing a orde from website checkout, only the issue is with rest API.